# Libgdx: unsupported combination of formats

Tags: java, opengl-es, libgdx, opengl-es-2.0

I have published my game on play store, but I receiving `frame buffer couldn't be constructed: unsupported combination of formats` error on some devices. Here is list of devices with this report:

```
Galaxy Ace2 (GT-I8160
Galaxy Note (GT-N7000)
maxwell_c7016
hsdroid
Galaxy S2 (GT-I9100)
```

Here is stack trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: frame buffer couldn't be constructed: unsupported combination of formats
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.FrameBuffer.build(FrameBuffer.java:204)
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.FrameBuffer.<init>(FrameBuffer.java:116)
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.FrameBuffer.<init>(FrameBuffer.java:98)
at com.ons.era.screens.DirectedGame.setScreen(DirectedGame.java:37)
at com.ons.era.EraGame.create(EraGame.java:21)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onSurfaceChanged(AndroidGraphics.java:241)
at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1455)
at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1216)
```

I try to find any solution on web , but without luck.

I use this settings in GDX Texture Packer I'm not sure if this is reason for crash

[image: Texture Packer settings]

Comment: it's not a problem with textures but with the framebuffer you are creating.  see https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/3f49a73ae24014964db439cd7d98a935dc30f13e/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/glutils/FrameBuffer.java#L129.  you should check the features you are requesting in libgdx and then see, if the mentioned devices do not support them.

Comment: can you give me simple code for this ? thanks

Comment: how can we give you your code?  also if you don't care about the generation of the devices mentioned above, just raise the bar so they get excluded.

Comment: Perhaps consider including the actual code that throws the exception (DirectedGame.java:37). http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3):

Look at the Javadoc for the constructor of FrameBuffer. If you are targeting GLES 2.0, then, you need to pick one of the formats listed there:

> `format - the format of the color buffer; according to the OpenGL ES`
>   `2.0 spec, only RGB565, RGBA4444 and RGB5_A1 are color-renderable`

There are some devices that support more than the minimum required by GLES 2.0, but to the best of my knowledge, there is no simpler way to test for support than to catch this exception. What I do is construct the FrameBuffer with the format I prefer, catch the IllegalStateException, and use one of the guaranteed formats if necessary.

For example:

```
FrameBuffer frameBuffer;
try {
    frameBuffer = new FrameBuffer(Format.RGBA8888, 1024, 1024, false, false);
} catch (IllegalStateException e){
    frameBuffer = new FrameBuffer(Format.RGB565, 1024, 1024, false, false);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In this context frame buffer means your screen, not a texture. Maybe you are creating a frame buffer with unsupported depth bits or color components (e.g. alpha). There may be a way to query supported formats.

Comment: thanks for answer. Can you please give me tip how can I detect and solve this unsupported depth bits or color components. Is there any tools to check that, because I don't know what "unsupported " mean.

Comment: I haven't used LibGDX, but according to their documentation, you can query available formats from Graphics object returned by Application: http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/Graphics.html